# OverFlowException with IDataRecord

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I had a x64 WinForms program working fine with MySQL and ODBC connector. Until one machine made me change to x86 and now I have this line of code:

`var someValue = data.GetString(3);`

and throws me a OverFlowException. I tryed to change to:

`var someValue = (string)data[3];`

but is the same throuble. I have more problems when it comes to get numbers.

I switch my plataform to "Any CPU" but nothing changes.

Exception:

> `System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an
>   overflow. at 
>       System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSqlType(Int32 i)    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.DbCache.AccessIndex(Int32 i)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32 i)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)    at
>   MyProject.Clases.Catalogos.Cartt..ctor(IDataRecord data) at
>   c:\Users\Develop\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyProject\Clases\Catalog\Cartt.cs:línea 113`

any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide us with the full exception if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolve this by setting plataform preference as x86 in project properties.